# Estimated Variance in LinearModelFit

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Suppose that `lmModel` is a linear model which is fit using `LinearModelFit`. How come `lmModel["EstimatedVariance"]` is not equal to `Variance[lmModel["FitResiduals"]]`? How is `lmModel["EstimatedVariance"]` actually calculated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RegressionCommon/ref/EstimatedVariance.html) page spells out how `EstimatedVariance` is computed. It is the "squared sum of `FitResiduals` divided by the degrees of freedom $n-p$.  A linear regression will also have an intercept term, in addition to terms corresponding to each of the predictor columns.

For example,

```
headings = ExampleData[{"Statistics", "FisherIris"}, "ColumnHeadings"];
data = ExampleData[{"Statistics", "FisherIris"}];
ds = Dataset[Map[AssociationThread[headings, #] &, data]]
```

[image: ds]

Subsetting the data so that we can see a nice linear trend:

```
d = ds[Select[#["PetalLength"] > 2 &]];
ListPlot[d[All, {"SepalLength", "PetalLength"}]]
```

[image: lp]

Fitting the model (converting the `Dataset` data into normal values):

```
lmModel = LinearModelFit[
  d[All, {"SepalLength", "PetalLength"}] // Normal // Values
 , x, x];
```

we can extract the Estimated Variance:

```
lmModel["EstimatedVariance"]
(* 0.21594 *)
```

The Fitted Residuals can be extracted:

```
fr = lmModel["FitResiduals"];
```

and compute its variance with the help of `Variance`:

```
Variance[fr]
(* 0.213759 *)
```

Explicitly computing the unbiased variance (same as `Variance`):

```
Total[(fr - Mean[fr])^2]/(Length[fr] - 1)
(* 0.213759 *)
```

Recalling that we have to subtract out two degrees of freedom $(p=2)$ due to the intercept and the slope term:

```
Total[(fr - Mean[fr])^2]/(Length[fr] - 2)
(* 0.21594 *)
```

which explains the origins of these Properties.